# Homogenous rotational cylinder height $h$ is deformed, find the volume and some other stuff

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, physics, classical-mechanics

We have a homogenous rotational cylinder height $h$ that is deformed on the axis into a rotational body:

$$\Omega = \{(x,y,z): -h/2 \leq z \leq h/2 \,\, \text{and} \,\, x^2+y^2 \leq r_0(1 + \epsilon \sin(\frac{\pi z}{h}))\}$$

We need to find its density if the mass stays the same.

My try:

We find the volume of the new body: $\iiint_\Omega dV$

If we use cylindrical coordinates:

$x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

$0 \leq r^2 \leq r_0(1+ \epsilon \sin(\pi z/h))$

So bounds of the integral are:
$0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{r_0(1+ \epsilon \sin(\pi z/h))}$

$-h/2 \leq z \leq h/2$

However, I don't know on what interval is $\phi$

What I would do then is: $\frac{V_1}{\rho_1}= \frac{V_2}{\rho_2} \implies: \rho_2 = \frac{V_2 \rho_1}{V_1}$

Then after I would do the first part, the question also is to calculate the momentum about the symmetric axis. But first I need to know how to do the upper.

Comment: The notation is a bit weird – one might have expected $r_0$ to be the undeformed radius, but it's actually the square of that.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to their content by preceding them with `\left`and `\right`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no bound on $\phi$, since the body is rotationally symmetric about the $z$ axis. You can calculate the volume as the integral of the areas of the circular discs it consist of:

$$
V=\int_{-h/2}^{h/2}\pi r_0\left(1+\epsilon\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}h\right)\right)\mathrm  dz=\pi r_0h\;.
$$

Comment: In classes we did the integral bound for $\phi \in [0, 2\pi]$. I guess that is wrong ?

Comment: @VLC: I don't understand what you mean by "we did the integral bound for $\phi\in[0,2\pi]$". Do you mean you integrated $\phi$ over $[0,2\pi]$?. If so: Yes, that's right, $\phi$ is only defined on the interval $[0,2\pi]$. By "There's no bound on $\phi$", I didn't mean that $\phi$ isn't restricted to $[0,2\pi]$; I meant that there are no specific constraints on $\phi$ from this specific problem in addition to the restriction of $\phi$ to $[0,2\pi]$ inherent in the definition of cylindrical coordinates (which I took for granted).